# Align JQuery UI slider values points aligment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, slider

I'm using jQuery UI slider with 6 points and I also have a 6 divs above the slider and I would like to position points in the slider in the middle of each div above.

So is there a way how to specify value position in jquery UI slider?

Here is and example of what I'm doing [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbqr8/117/)

```
$('#slider').slider({
    value:1,
    min: 1,
    max: 6,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {

    }
});


<div id="assesment-filter">
    <div class="assesments-wrapper">
        <div id="1" class="assesment">1</div>
        <div id="2" class="assesment">2</div>
        <div id="3" class="assesment">3</div>
        <div id="4" class="assesment">4</div>
        <div id="5" class="assesment">5</div>
        <div id="6" class="assesment">6</div>
    </div>
<div id="slider"></div>
</div>


.assesments-wrapper {
    height: 33px;
}

.assesment {
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: rgb(219,219,219);
    line-height: 33px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.assesment:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

.ui-slider-handle{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #2CBFD9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.ui-slider-handle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-slider{
  background-color: rgb(219,219,219);
  height: 3px;
  width: 203px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you, I just did the math.

The anchor's(Blue color) width is `15px + (1px + 1px)(Border) = 17px;`

If you inspect the `ui-slider` the anchor start at `left:0%` and then increment based on the max,min and step value.

Here in your case it is: `max=6`, `min=1`, `step=1`
Hence : Increment in percentage is `100*step/(max-min)` which is `20%`.

And each `Assesment` is `33px+1px=34px` hence causes the wrapper div to be `34*6=204px` approx.

Now to center the slider anchor we need the slider to start at `left:8.5px` and also `position:relative` to the wrapper as `anchor's width =  17px, assesment's width = 34px`.(I cannot explain better than this)

Now at the first step, the anchor is placed at the center of first div.... Half work done...D

Now as the last step is at position `left:100%` the anchor is placed outside the slider. That is why we need the width of ui-slider to be

> **ui-slider width** =  **width of wrapper** - 2*(**width of anchor**).

If `left=80%` was the last step, it would have been

> **ui-slider width** =  **width of wrapper** - 1*(**width of
>   anchor**).

Hence ui-slider width = `204-2*17 = 170px;`

Now as the first and last step are aligned, everything else inside also falls into the place.(Hurray).

Including the fiddle having the solution: [Fiddle For Slider](http://jsfiddle.net/jbqr8/122/).

Essential Code for reference:

```
.assesments-wrapper {
        height: 33px;
        width: fit-content;
    }

.ui-slider{
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(219,219,219);
  height: 3px;
  width: 171px;
  left:8.5px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

PS: I am sure, there are better solution then this. I just found this question and thought whether I can do this without searching on Google.

Found a bit weird solution. Still I will be sharing this on SO :).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend some of jquery ui code.

Basic html structure can be

```
<section class="wrapper">  
  <div class="slider2"></div>
  <br><br>
</section>
```

Please try following pen:
http://codepen.io/solankidhaval/pen/BjMjVd